# python flask query object type

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

What type of object does flasks "query" method return?
for example if i had a query like this one:

```
messages = current_user.messages_sent.order_by(Message.timestamp.desc()).filter_by(author=current_user).all()
```

then what type of object would messages be?

Comment: Depends on what `current_user.messages_sent` is, but `all()` runs the query and returns a list of <something>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html)

```
all()
```

> Return the results represented by this Query as a list.